# Netsuite Invoice and Item Fulfillment

Tags: netsuite, invoice

After surfing the web for more than 3 months, most of the problems that will face NetSuite users are related to Item Fulfillment. I want to know what is the relation between the Invoice and Item Fulfillment.
Invoice will not be created until we fulfill the order, so, there must be a relation between Invoice & IF.

But unfortunately, I cannot get at least Item Fulfillment Order #.

Our Customers are asking to include the Number in the Invoice, but, there is no relation between the 2 records unless one field which is (created from) and this field is getting the Sales Order Number and it is useless to us, since we may issue from one sales order many Item Fulfillment Transactions.

Could anyone suggest any help or hint on how to reach Item Fulfillment # from Invoice Record?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no system link between an Invoice and an Item Fulfillment.

Sales Orders are linked to one or more Item Fulfillments, and one or more Invoices, but as far as NetSuite is concerned there is nothing connecting any specific fulfillment to any specific invoice. In fact you could have products from multiple fulfillments that are invoiced together, or vice versa, a single fulfillment with multiple invoices.

If you want to store a link between the two documents you would need to customize this yourself using scripting and a custom field.

Comment: Yes I noticed that, I thought I am missing something that is available without coding. Netsuite must Provide this, it is recommended to mention Item fulfillment number in the invoice.

Answer (score 0):

functionally it is possible only if the policy goes by One SO-One IF-One Inv.
Else you may need to look for scripting.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna run a report from saved search showing SO with item IF and related invoice, follow these steps :

Criteria :
type : is SalesOrder
applying transaction : type is IF
billing transaction : type is Invoice

Results:
Document Number (showing SO#)
Amount
quantity
Applying transaction : Document Number showing IF
Billing transaction : Document Number showing Invoice
Billing transaction : Amount (Invoice's amount)